# Is sys.stderr a block device or character device in Python3?

Tags: python, c, linux, buffer, device

In C language, if I write codes like this:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <unistd.h>
int main() 
{
    while(1)
    {
        fprintf(stdout,"hello-std-out");
        fprintf(stderr,"hello-std-err");
        sleep(1);
    }
    return 0;
}
```

The stdout will not be displayed because it's a block device. But stderr will be displayed because it's not.

However, if I write similar codes in **Python3**:

```
import sys
import time
if __name__ == '__main__':
    while True:
        sys.stdout.write("hello-std-out")
        sys.stderr.write("hello-stderr")
        time.sleep(1)
```

Both stdout and stderr will not be displayed if I don't flush these buffers. Does that mean sys.stderr is also a block device in Python?

Comment: The block/character designation is not strictly related to buffering. See the wikipedia [device file](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Device_file) entry.

Comment: By default Python buffers stdout. You can force stdin, stdout, and stderr to be totally unbuffered by using the `-u` flag: `python -u test.py`.

Comment: @unutbu I tried to add `-u`, but the stderr still can't be displayed

Comment: That's interesting. I see stderr whether I use `-u` or not (using Ubuntu and a gnome-terminal).

Comment: @pst is right: buffers and blocks are not synonomous. Most systems use a character device for STDOUT/STDERR, but they buffer STDOUT. STDERR tends to be unbuffered, which is why you sometimes have confusing interweaving of STDOUT and STDERR.

Comment: Are you running from command line, or using some kind of IDE? IDE can provide internal buffering. Runs fine on ubuntu even without -u option.

Comment: @unutbu weird, I see sterr if I use `python 2.6`, but can't see it using `python3`

Comment: @unutbu For python3, even I use `-u` in terminal, I can see nothing.

Answer (score 4):

If you don't see stderr then you are on Python3 where text IO layer is line-bufferred when connected to a tty and block-bufferred otherwise regardless `-u` option.

The bufferring issues are unrelated to character/block devices.